# How to keep field readonly?

Tags: c#, initialization, member, readonly

Let's suppose, that we have the following class:

```
class C
{
    private readonly DataType data;
    private readonly AdditionalType additional;

    C(DataType newData)
    {
        data = newData;
        // LONG code evaluating additional
    }

    C(OtherType newData)
    {
        // eval data from newData
        // the same LONG code evaluating additional
    }
}
```

Both `data` and `additional` remain unchanged through the whole life of C. However, there is a code smell: the section evaluating `additional` is doubled in both constructors. The natural choice is then to extract it to another method:

```
class C
{
    private readonly DataType data;
    private readonly AdditionalType additional;

    private void EvalAdditional()
    {
        // LONG code evaluating additional
    }

    C(DataType newData)
    {
        data = newData;
        EvalAdditional();
    }

    C(OtherType newData)
    {
        // eval data from newData
        EvalAdditional();
    }
}
```

But then additional no longer can be readonly (beacuse it is not initialized in ctor).

How to solve this problem in an elegant way?

Comment: Does the evaluation of `additional` depend on the constructor arguments? If not you can just move the evaluation to another private constructor and call that from your public constructors.

Comment: *...// LONG code...* evaluating anything in a constructor is a code smell in itself. From MSDN: Constructors should not do much work other than capture the constructor parameters. The cost of any other processing should be delayed until required.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just let the method `EvalAdditional` return the `additional` object (instead of `void`).

```
readonly DataType data;
readonly AdditionalType additional;

AdditionalType EvalAdditional()
{
    // LONG code evaluating additional
    return additional;
}

C(DataType newData)
{
    data = newData;
    additional = EvalAdditional();
}

C(OtherType newData)
{
    // eval data from newData
    additional = EvalAdditional();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

If the evaluation of `additional` does not depend on the arguments given to the other constructors, you can just move it to a private constructor and call that from your public constructors:

```
private C()
{
    //long code evaluating additional
}

C(DataType newData)
    : this()
{
    data = newData;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like this:

```
C(DataType newData)
    :this ()
{
    data = newData;
}

C(OtherType newData)
    :this ()
{
    // eval data from newData
}

private C()
{
    EvalAdditional();
}
```

Although that depends heavily on what EvalAdditional is doing, you could pass parameters if required.

Comment: The question was how to keep the `additional` field `readonly`.